# How to intercept the end of data-binding in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I am developing a web-application using Angular Js framework, with HTML5 and with the help of jQuery, when it is needed. 
The question is:

I have some fields whose values depend on the result of an AJAX call. This request returns a JSON and the fields of this JSON become the values of many  tags.

For example, in the HTML code, I have:

```
<span>Data Nascita: <b><span id="patientBirthdate">{{patient.birthDate}}</span></b></span>
```

And in my controller, I have this request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    success:function(result){
        $scope.person = result;

    },
    error: function(xhr,status,error){
        console.log ("error in receiving person's data");
    }
});
```

This data-binding works properly.

The question is: how can I intercept the end of the operation of data-binding (the end of the filling of the {{patient.birthDate}} field) to somehow call on this field another javascript method?

My goal is to "shorten" the value of this field, after the filling made by Angular, with a jQuery plugin, with a call of this type:

```
$("#patientBirthdate").shorten({showChars: 15, moreText: ' >>', lessText: ' <<'});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't need jQuery for anything you have shown. Use angular to do all of it. A simple directive and filter for the `shorten` and use `$http` for ajax. get out of jQuery thinking mode when working with angular

Comment: This is the highest voted angular post on this site [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/SQuVy/751/ here is something you can do with `$watch`.

whenever change occures to an object callback is called,

ex.

```
angular.module('watchApp', []).controller('watchCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;

    $scope.$watch('a', function() {
        // change happened here do something
        $scope.b=$scope.a;

//OR you can call your method here

        }, true);
    });
```

I am here assigning value of a to b when a is changed.

Comment: I know I am saying `$watch` can be used for the purpose.. its just an example

Comment: @charlietfl.. its just to tell any method can be there.. if there should or shouldnt be dom manipulation is not the context of this question.

Comment: so that's an excuse for providing an answer with bad practices in it? Put it in a directive where it belongs

Comment: @charlietfl removed it.. so its not a bad practice now.. is it ok? And making directive and all that stuff would quite complicate this answer.. OP just requires **how to intercept**